# Recursive functions examples

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that the following functions are primitive recursive

- f(n)=n(n+1)/2
- f(n,k)= $(n^{k+1}-1)/(n-1)$ si n $\neq$ 1, f(1,k)=k+1
- Max(m,n)
- n!

The problem is that I don't how to write it, for example in the guide book, define
h(x,y)=x*y es pr (the product). Let f(x)=Z(x), g(x,y,z)=x+z then

x*0=Z(x)=0

x * S(y)=g(x,y,x * y)=x+x*y

So, I try to do it the same for example in n!: f(x)=S(Z(x)) it would be 0!=S(Z(x))=1 and I know that for another numbers is the productory but I don't know how to write with g(x,y,z) or something like that. I would apprecciate your help at least one to do the another please.

Thanks.

Comment: The guide book makes no sense. What is Z?  For x^y, define x^0 = 1, x^(n+1)= x^n * x.

Comment: Z(x)=0 is the constant function 0

Comment: That helps but it is still difficult to understand and seems wrong for using + when × seems appropiate.  Is the guide book making this stuff unduely complicated?

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest example the anothers has more functions

Answer (score 0):

To define n! recursevely, 0! = 1, (n+1)! = (n+1) × n!.
For the first f, note that f(n) = 0 + 1 +...+ n.